# How would I format a string like Monday-Saturday into an array of the included days?

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing quite a bit of data that has the format Monday-Thursday or Tuesday-Saturday. How can I format that into an array of the included days without a ton of regex's? Maybe similarly for times such as 11am-8pm

Comment: Please provide an example of a string and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any regex to do that. You need the build-in [date and time classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$str = 'Saturday-Thursday';

list($begin, $end) = array_map(fn($d) => new DateTime($d), explode('-', $str));

$end = $end->modify($end < $begin ? '+8 days':'+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$result = array_map(fn($d) => $d->format('l'), [...$daterange]);

print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/NvPgC)

Same thing for hours:

```
$str = '11am-8pm';

list($begin, $end) = explode('-', $str);

$begin = new DateTime($begin);
$end = new DateTime($end);
$end = $end->modify('+1 hour');

$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$result = array_map(fn($d) => $d->format('ga'), iterator_to_array($daterange));

print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/iTo9h)

All you have to know are the different date/time formats that are in the PHP manual.

Note that if you want to go from 11pm to 1am, [you need to add a day to the `$end` object](https://3v4l.org/epcMB).

Answer (score -1):

What about making two from-to variables by exploding the string by "-", then convert the day to number?